# Minimize symbols to represent a non-negative integer across N unary buckets

Tags: optimization, number-systems

Imagine you wish to encode a non-negative integer across N buckets, where each bucket can hold a unary number.  The probability of an integer being given as input to the encoder is specified by a function P(i) which sums to 1.

- If `N = 1`, you more or less have to encode the number in unary.  So if you want to express 42, you will need to use 42 symbols, all in the first (and only) bucket.
- If `N = 2`, you start getting options.  Example: you might say that the second bucket is the tens place.  So expressing 42 could be done with 2 symbols in the first bucket, and 4 in the second, for a total of 6.

P is fixed, but you don't a-priori know what N is.  What's desired is a system of encoding which for a given N will use (on average) as few unary "digits" as possible to encode a number from P.

I don't want to prescribe what kind of function P is--it could be uniform within a range (so long as it included 0), or gaussian or whatever.  But having it specified seems necessary to make the problem one that has "a solution".

I'm curious if this maps to an existing problem, or if someone here would have an approach to addressing it...

Answer (score 1):

Just to make things a bit easier notationally, we can represent each encoding as an $N$-tuple where the $i$th component is the number of items in the $i$th bucket. Additionally, I'll use the notation $e_N(n)$ to represent the encoding of $n$ using $N$ buckets. So in your examples, $e_1(42) = (42)$ and $e_2(42) = (4, 2)$.

In order to optimize our encoding, we need to see which integers occur the most frequently. So first, sort the integers as $n_1, n_2, \dots$ such that $P(n_i) \geq P(n_{i+1})$ for all $i$.

Since $n_1$ occurs most frequently, we want to represent it with as few symbols as possible. Thus, we'll represent $n_1$ as, $e_N(n_1) = (0, \dots ,0)$. Thus, $n_1$ is encoded with zero symbols.

Next, look at how many encodings have one symbol. There are exactly $N$ such encodings. Thus, we'll encode the next $N$ integers using those encodings:

$e_N(n_2) = (0, 0, \dots, 0, 0, 1)$

$e_N(n_3) = (0,0, \dots, 0, 1, 0)$

$\dots$

$e_N(n_N) = (0,1, \dots, 0, 0, 0)$

$e_N(n_{N+1}) = (1,0, \dots, 0, 0, 0)$

Next, we look at the number of encodings with exactly $2$ symbols and we assign all the currently unassigned integers at the front of our list to those encodings. We then look at the encodings with exactly $3$ symbols and repeat the same process. Then do the same for $4$ symbols, $5$ symbols, and so on and so forth.

As an example suppose I had $2$ buckets and after ordering my list of integers, I get $15, 3, 4, 7, 2, 8, 5, 1, \dots$. Then, my encodings will be,

$e_2(15) = (0,0)$

$e_2(3) = (0,1)$

$e_2(4) = (1,0)$

$e_2(7) = (0,2)$

$e_2(2) = (1,1)$

$e_2(8) = (2,0)$

$e_2(5) = (0,3)$

$e_2(1) = (1,2)$

$\dots$

Comment: That's an easy-to-follow approach... but it seems to have a weakness in optimizing something like P(0) = .34, P(1) = .33, P(2) = .33 -- in the sense that it seems there's more priority to encode that it's one of the two .33 cases vs. the .34 case.  I guess I was wondering about something less "counting-oriented" and more, uh, "equationy"  :-)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how that example would be seen as a weakness. If we have $2$ buckets, then since $0$ has the highest probability of occurring, then $e_2(0) = (0,0)$. Then $1$ and $2$ would be encoded as an encoding that has two symbols, e.g. $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. The expected number of symbols of an encoding is then $P(0)(0)+P(1)(1)+P(2)(1) = 0.66$.

Comment: You can make it more "equationy" if you define and implement the following functions. Let $f(n)$ be the index of the integer $n$ in the list of sorted integers where the integers are sorted in decreasing order based on probability of occuring. And let $g_N(n)$ be the $n$th encoding with $N$ buckets (where encodings are sorted based on the number of total symbols). Then, you have that $e_N(n) = g(f(n))$.

Comment: My apologies, that last equation should be $e_N(n) = g_N(f(n))$.

Comment: Indeed, that particular example didn't show the weakness, oops! :-/ But the abstract idea I was thinking of was just if there's a very minimal difference in the probabilities of some set of integers...and then there are a lot of less common integers, your plan may be greedily using low symbol count for a negligible optimization point. Another strategy might be able to compress better by using symbols in less of a 1:1 way, like *"if bucket 0 has an even number of symbols, it means so-and-so"* which sets up what mean the rest of the encoding is relative to.  I'll try coming up with an example.

Comment: One of the issues is that there may exists $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $P(a) = P(b)$ yet $a \neq b$. In that case, then the ordering of the integers as described by the process above is not unique and thus the ordering would have to explicitly state which of the two elements comes first a priori. In the worst case scenario, you have a large finite number of integers all with uniform probability of occurring and thus you need to supply the complete ordering yourself apriori. I suppose in this case, "the encoding of the encoding" starts becomes hectic and results in a giant lookup table.

Comment: Also, all of this is assuming that the integers being fed into the encoder is independent of each other. This scheme might not work the best if the probability of a certain integer occurring is dependent on the previous integers encoded. For example, if you were instead encoding individual characters from a piece of English text, then the probability of a certain character appearing is most definitely going to be dependent on the previous characters encoded (e.g. the probability of 'q' being the next letter when the previous two characters were 'th' is likely to be $0$).